# Cannot receive packets from vernemq broker : but when session disconnects, it works

Tags: mqtt, esp32, mqtt-vernemq

I am trying to communicate with VerneMQ using ESP32.

Problem:

Sometimes local devices with esp32 cannot receive any packets from VerneMQ broker.
*This happens rarely and once the local device can't receive packets, it won't be received after that.*

However when I disconnect the devices session, it receives packets for a few seconds. To force a disconnection I am using the command `sudo vmq-admin session disconnect | grep client_id='client_id`. Unfortunately, 'the few seconds' the packet received is not constant, after that, devices cannot receive packets again.
terribly Debugging is difficult because there is no storage space on the local device.

Could it be something to do with the QOS settings?
or
vernemq configuration?

What I tried:

1. repeat the cmd `sudo vmq-admin session disconnect | grep client_id='client_id` about 10~20 times.
2. use the cmd `sudo vmq-admin session disconnect | grep client_id='client_id`, then send reset cmd to local device.

Result:
I usually got same results.
Local devices receive packets few seconds then seems blocked the packets again. Surprisingly, the packet is received again after a certain period of time.

**Configuration**

1. esp32=client /Role: publish raw sensor data and subscribe control commands from broker
   chip: esp32-wroom-32
   ide: esp-idf v4.3.1
   os: Windows

```
mqtt_cfg={
.host = CONFIG_MQTT_HOST,
        .port = 8883,
        .username = "username",
        .password = "password",
        .transport = MQTT_TRANSPORT_OVER_SSL, //.disable_clean_session = 1, //if disable_clean_session is true, resume communication with the client(after subscription, receive last message)
        .client_cert_pem = (const char *)client_cert_pem_start,
        .client_key_pem = (const char *)client_key_pem_start,
        .cert_pem = (const char *)server_cert_pem_start,
        .keepalive = 60,
        .buffer_size = 2048,
        .client_id = client_id
}
```

1-1) publish : QOS 0, retain false
1-2) subscribe : QOS 0, retain false

2. VerneMQ

Except for certification-related settings, all are default values.
`plugins.vmq_bridge = off` so `keepalive`, timeout setting is default.

Example esp32 code:

```
void app_main(void)
{
    ESP_LOGD(TAG, "[APP] Startup..");
    ESP_LOGD(TAG, "[APP] Free memory: %d bytes", esp_get_free_heap_size());
    ESP_LOGD(TAG, "[APP] IDF version: %s", esp_get_idf_version());
    esp_log_level_set("*", ESP_LOG_INFO);
    esp_log_level_set("esp-tls", ESP_LOG_VERBOSE);
    esp_log_level_set("MQTT_CLIENT", ESP_LOG_VERBOSE);
    //esp_log_level_set("MODEL_Y0_ESP32", ESP_LOG_VERBOSE);
    esp_log_level_set("TRANSPORT_BASE", ESP_LOG_VERBOSE);
    esp_log_level_set("TRANSPORT", ESP_LOG_VERBOSE);
    esp_log_level_set("OUTBOX", ESP_LOG_VERBOSE);

    initialise_wifi();
    s_mqtt_event_group = xEventGroupCreate(); //Create EventGroup for MQTT START after first WiFI Connection
}

static void sendMQTT(uint8_t *pBuffer, uint8_t size)
{
    if (esp_mqtt_client_publish(mqtt_client, mqtt_topic, (const char *)pBuffer, size, 0, 0); != -1)
    {
        ESP_LOGD(TAG, "pub success");
    }
    else
    {
        ESP_LOGE(TAG, "pub failed");
    }
}
```

I deleted part of code

sendmqtt function is executed in a different thread after raw data sampling

Comment: It seems most likely that the issue is in your client code (at QOS0 the broker will just send any messages you have subscribed to and not wait for a response). Can you please provide a [minimal, reproducible, example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? (i.e. a very minimal version of your ESP32 code that demonstrates the issue).

Comment: Thanks Brits! If it's because of the qos settings, message packets can be expected to be delivered. but once device get stuck it doesn't get better until send command vernemq session dissconnect..

Comment: My comment was more indicating that the QOS level used means its likely the issue is with the ESP32 code (because the broker will just chuck messages at you; it doesn't really care if you don't process them). The code you added appears incomplete (e.g. where is `xTimer_fail_mqtt_sub` defined?) and it would be useful to see what the ESP32 is logging. Note that I have no experience with the ESP-MQTT library so comments are based on knowledge of the protocol and issues encountered with other libraries.

Comment: Thanks for answers!I know the code looks incomplete. I want to show all the source code, but I can't show it because it is owned by the company,,, and xTimer_fail_mqtt_sub is defined.

Comment: plus, that situation(problem) is very rarely happen & there is no way to log esp32 in client's device.

Answer (score 0):

You can trace that session on the command line like this:
`sudo vmq-admin trace client client-id=client_id`

This will give you all the events for that session but from the perspective of the broker. If you see an `MQTT SEND`, it'll be a message published from the broker to your consumer. This should determine whether the message goes out, at least.

Also: Does your client implement re-connect logic. Are you sure it re-subscribes to topics?

Comment: thank you andre! it's better to suggest server team to trace all client-id...

Comment: plus, esp32 reconnection logic is defined inside esp-idf sdk. and usually it is automatically reconnected, i tested.

Comment: This is probably just a copy/paste error but I noticed `sudo vmq-admin session disconnect | grep client_id='client_id` in your post. To disconnect a client use `sudo vmq-admin session disconnect client_id='client_id'`.